# Change the color of class on click is not working Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am making an app in **Angular 2**, and the functionality is same like stackoverflow **vote up and down**, The app is working fine in my visual studio code.

**Problems:**

(1)Why up and down arrow are  are not showing in Stackblitz
[My app StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7d3f1h)

(2) I want to change the color of arrows when the arrow is highlighted/clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add this in your index.html to import bootstrap glyphicons :

`<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />`

2. Change `[style.Color]` to **`[style.color]`** in the `<i>` tags